# How to set a window to display on every workspace on OS X?

Tags: macos, workspace

I have 2 screens and 4 workspaces. I'd like one screen (which displays only 1 window: a terminal) to be "pinned" and do not change when I switch workspaces (only windows on the other screen should change). Can I achieve that on OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click it in the Dock > Options > Assign to... All Desktops.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For an app (like [Touch Bar Simulator](https://github.com/sindresorhus/touch-bar-simulator)) that has a floating window without an icon in the Dock, you have to find the .app file and drag it to your Dock.

From there you can use the method that [Tesujin mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/1083552) to have it available on all workspaces by right clicking on app icon, Options, Assign To All Desktops.

Answer (score 2):

I've been pulling my hair out over this one.

I recently changed to a new work computer and after getting most things set up how I like, that's been driving me crazy. There's a few dock features I rely heavily on and the biggest simple one is just setting Finder to appear on all desk tops.

Expected Behavior:
By assigning finder to all desktops, when I open finder (through spotlight, dock, tab_cmd switching etc) it will aways open my current finder windows on whatever monitor/space/desktop I open it on.

With this computer on Catalina 10.15.16. (same as my last) the feature doesn't work.

Actual behavior:
If I set finder to assign to a specific desktop, it works, and will only open on that desktop. e.g. I have two monitors, each with 4 desktops/spaces.

If I set it to desktop 4(desktop8 out of all of them) on monitor 2, opening finder will always bring me to a finder window on that desktop/space.

If I set it to all Desktops, with a finder window on desktop 8 (4th space on monitor 2) opening finder will bring the finder window to the front of any desktop on monitor 2. It used to carry this same behavior. i.e. I should be able to on monitor 1 (my laptop) open finder, and despite it last being used on desktop 8, it would appear on desktop 1 as well.

This is a small feature that always makes it easy to constantly drag and drop things in and out of my downloads folder.

It appears as if that no longer carries through with both monitors, leaving me to only use the feature on my second monitor and having to manually drag the window to the other monitor if I want it there.

Anyone experienced this or have any thoughts? I've tried the above solutions, several reboots and PRAM/SMC resets to no avail.